# Solve multiple independent optimizations in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to minimize a cost function for a large number (1000s) of different inputs. Obviously, this can be implemented by looping over [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) or any other minimization routine. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def cost(x, a, b):
    return np.sum((np.sum(a * x.reshape(a.shape), axis=1) - b)**2)

a = np.random.randn(500, 40)
b = np.array(np.arange(500))

x = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    res = sp.optimize.minimize(cost, np.zeros(40), args=(a[None, i], b[None, i]))
    x.append(res.x)
```

It finds `x[i, :]` that minimize `cost` for each `a[i, :]` and `b[i]`, but this is very slow. I guess looping over `minimize` causes considerable overhead.

A partial solution is to solve for all `x` simultaneously:

```
res = sp.optimize.minimize(cost, np.zeros_like(a), args=(a, b))
```

This is even slower than the loop. `minimize` does not know that elements in `x` are group-wise independent. So it computes the full hessian although a block-diagonal matrix would be sufficient, considering the problem structure. This is slow and overflows my computer's memory.

Is there any way to inform `minimize` or another optimization function about the problem structure so that it can solve multiple indepentent optimizations in a single function call? (Similar to [certain options supported by Matlab's `fsolve`](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116033-solving-multiple-independent-non-linear-equations?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).)

Comment: `minimize` has many optional parameters.  Do any make sense to you?

Comment: None of them seem to do what I need, but I can't rule out that I'm looking for the wrong thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First, a solution:**

Turns out [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) supports exploiting the structure of the jacobian by setting the `jac_sparsity` argument.

The `least_squares` function works slightly different than `minimize` so the cost function needs to be rewritten to return residuals instead:

```
def residuals(x, a, b):
    return np.sum(a * x.reshape(a.shape), axis=1) - b
```

The jacobian has block-diagonal sparsity structure, given by

```
jacs = sp.sparse.block_diag([np.ones((1, 40), dtype=bool)]*500)
```

And calling the optimization routine:

```
res = sp.optimize.least_squares(residuals, np.zeros(500*40),
                                jac_sparsity=jacs, args=(a, b))
x = res.x.reshape(500, 40)
```

---

**But is it really faster?**

```
%timeit opt1_loopy_min(a, b)        # 1 loop, best of 3: 2.43 s per loop
%timeit opt2_loopy_min_start(a, b)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 2.55 s per loop
%timeit opt3_loopy_lsq(a, b)        # 1 loop, best of 3: 13.7 s per loop
%timeit opt4_dense_lsq(a, b)        # ValueError: array is too big; ...
%timeit opt5_jacs_lsq(a, b)         # 1 loop, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop
```

Conclusions:

1. There is no obvious difference between the original solution (`opt1`) and re-use of the starting point (`opt2`) without sorting.
2. looping over `least_squares` (`opt3`) is considerable slower than looping over `minimize` (`opt1`, `opt2`).
3. The problem is too big to naiively run with `least_squares` because the jacobian matrix does not fit in memory.
4. **Exploiting the sparsity structure of the jacobian in `least_squares` (`opt5`) seems to be the fastest approach.**

---

This is the timing test environment:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def cost(x, a, b):
    return np.sum((np.sum(a * x.reshape(a.shape), axis=1) - b)**2)

def residuals(x, a, b):
    return np.sum(a * x.reshape(a.shape), axis=1) - b

a = np.random.randn(500, 40)
b = np.arange(500)

def opt1_loopy_min(a, b):
    x = []
    x0 = np.zeros(a.shape[1])
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        res = sp.optimize.minimize(cost, x0, args=(a[None, i], b[None, i]))
        x.append(res.x)
    return np.stack(x)

def opt2_loopy_min_start(a, b):
    x = []
    x0 = np.zeros(a.shape[1])
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        res = sp.optimize.minimize(cost, x0, args=(a[None, i], b[None, i]))
        x.append(res.x)
        x0 = res.x
    return np.stack(x)

def opt3_loopy_lsq(a, b):
    x = []
    x0 = np.zeros(a.shape[1])
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        res = sp.optimize.least_squares(residuals, x0, args=(a[None, i], b[None, i]))
        x.append(res.x)
    return x

def opt4_dense_lsq(a, b):
    res = sp.optimize.least_squares(residuals, np.zeros(a.size), args=(a, b))
    return res.x.reshape(a.shape)

def opt5_jacs_lsq(a, b):
    jacs = sp.sparse.block_diag([np.ones((1, a.shape[1]), dtype=bool)]*a.shape[0])
    res = sp.optimize.least_squares(residuals, np.zeros(a.size), jac_sparsity=jacs, args=(a, b))
    return res.x.reshape(a.shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I guess looping over minimize causes considerable overhead.

Wrong guess. The time required for minimizing a function dwarfs any loop overhead.  There is no vectorization magic for this problem.

Some time can be saved by using a better starting point of minimization. First,  sort the parameters so that consecutive loops have similar parameters.  Then use the end point of previous minimization as a starting point of the next one:

```
a = np.sort(np.random.randn(500, 40), axis=0)   # sorted parameters
b = np.arange(500)   # no need for np.array here, np.arange is already an ndarray

x0 = np.zeros(40)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    res = minimize(cost, x0, args=(a[None, i], b[None, i]))
    x.append(res.x)
    x0 = res.x
```

This saves 30-40 percent of execution time in my test.

Another, minor, optimization to do is to preallocate an ndarray of appropriate size for resulting x-values, instead of using a list and `append` method. Before the loop: `x = np.zeros((500, 40))`; within the loop, `x[i, :] = res.x`.

Comment: Good idea to adapt the starting point but you sort the columns in `a` individually, which breaks the rows. Can you suggest a sorting criterion that does not break the rows and still gives a performance improvement? (Btw, it's not loop overhead I am concerned with but the overhead of checks and initializations inside `minimize` done repeatedly.)

Comment: Right, with vector parameters arranging them so that the rows are close to each other is a separate issue (worth another question or search). I did this for illustration because the numbers were random anyway. I still think the bulk of time will be spent on iteration within `minimize`. Adjusting the parameters of `minimize` (e..g, require less precision) may generate substantial time saving.